# Javascript can't connect to my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
</html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<button>Click Me!</button>
<p>K O N T S</p>

<script src="k.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JQuery2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

While my JS be like :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

        $("p").fadeOut();

    });



});
```

This just happened this morning.

The K O N T S won't fade out when I click the Button. Anyone knows why ?

*I've made this code very simple, but still dont get where is my fault(s).
*And the stuff also have been placed in a same folder.

Comment: It seems you are running that code before JQuery is even loaded. I don't know if that's your only problem, but it's certainly one.

Comment: include `<script src="k.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` after jQuery scritpt is loaded

Comment: also what is `JQuery2.js`

Comment: How would that happen ? I'm still new here. Sorry. | JQuery2.js is also a library.

Comment: Open your browser's JavaScript / developer console and read the errors

Comment: Btw, how to make sure that the JQuery loaded first ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your js files are not referenced properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

        $("p").fadeOut();

    });



});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
</html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<button>Click Me!</button>
<p>K O N T S</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I also type <script src="k.js"></script> ? Because that's the script I wrote for the HTML.

Comment: Your code should work. Just reference the jquery and other js files properly. Once the page is loaded, go to debugger mode and make sure that all necessary js files are loaded.

Comment: Tx, Problem solved. Just need to replace the <script> position. Tx guys, this web rocks !.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<button>Click Me!</button>
<p>K O N T S</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  //Do something with jQuery
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="k.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script>
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeOut();
  });
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```